# How to get error code from compiling integration tests

Tags: java, bash, maven, junit, serenity-bdd

I have this bash command that runs some integration tests

```
mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test -s ./settings.xml
```

This command results in this output.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   MyJavaIntegrationTestClass » UnsatisfiedDependency Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  39.037 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-08T16:42:26Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem here is that the code does not even compile and even says that there is 1 error but still I get a successful build.  I tried to capture the error code from the call and got a 0 (success) so couldn't use the error code to decide whether the tests ran ok or not.  What I am trying to do is fail the script if there are any compilation or test run failures and pass the script if there are not.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: First you should use `mvn clean verify -s ..` instead of calling the goal instead of using the life cycle...

Comment: based on the sample output ... what would you be looking for to indicate an issue? will it be sufficient to look for the string `[ERROR]`? are there other strings that need to be considered? would a simple `grep` of the output be sufficient or is there more to consider?

Comment: @markp-fuso I was hoping to not have to grep for error strings.

Comment: @khmarbaise I still get code 0 with this.

Comment: The test you are executing is failing... which looks like an integration test which should be executed via maven-failsafe-plugin... The error is: `UnsatisfiedDependency Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx...` furthermore you should configure maven-failsafe-plugin via `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>` because you seemed to using an older version before 3.0.0-MXX

Comment: If you aren't the original author of that program, maybe the testing program is successfully reporting that all unit-testing was "performed" successfully, but that one of those units failed the test in question.  There might in fact be no problem with "what" was reported, and that it is giving direction as to where to focus the next phase of debugging efforts.  Also, if make did not set the proper conditional, build could proceed without all the pieces you expected, under the "wrong" conditions.